# ImageView and draw image in precision coordinates

Tags: android

I have a problem with drawing image. How I can draw image in precision coorinates. I want to draw image in place where I touch the screen. How I can do this? I implement onTouch method where i get coordinates, but I don;t know how I can draw image in this place.

Comment: You want to draw image on canvas directly or only create(move) some imageView?

Comment: I only want draw image in place where I click and after that use animation on this image. Where I can better use animation after that. Canvas can animate some pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below to draw the image in touch co-ordinate

```
class Panel extends View {

        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Bitmap _scratch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.calvin_logo_small);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, x-point, y-point, null);
        }
    }
```